# urlencoding form data with windows-1252 charset in node.js

Tags: node.js, forms, url-encoding

I need to post a form that has been set to use windows-1252 charset for urlencoding its data. for simple characters, default encoding (utf8) works but it is the special characters that have to be encoded with the required charset.

the npm "request" package i am using does not allow setting any specific charset and uses utf8 by default underneath. i tried another package "Restler", which allows encoding to be set but it throws exception saying invalid charset when i specify windows-1252 (Node only offers a handful of encoding charsets (Buffer class) and windows-1252 is not one of them).

please let me know whether what i am trying to achieve is even possible in node nor not? for verification purposes, i created a little client in java and used apache's http client library with windows-1252 encoding and my request was successfully accepted by the server. so far, i have not been able to figure this out in node.

Comment: No modern-day web server is not able to deal with UTF-8 encoded URLs. Are you sure sure about this requirement?

Comment: yes i am sure. i mention in my OP that i managed to send my request with java client. when i set utf8 in that java client, the server fails to decode back to correct data. also, the html page that server sends in response are set to use windows-1252 charset.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the server?

Comment: can't tell you the hostname. but in chrome's developer tools i saw IIS 7.5. one can tell its an ASP.NET server by looking at the urls i.e. they end with .asp.

Comment: This server *definitely* handles UTF-8 encoded URLs. The error has to be be something else. Can you post URLs that work and some that don't?

Comment: its the form data to be exact, not the url. i ll explain it with the character that is causing the issue for now, ‘ (ascii code 8216). with windows-1252, this encodes to %91. and with utf8 it encodes to %E2%80%98. the server only accepts data when the character is encoded to %91. which is only possible with windows-1252.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120705/discussion-between-tomalak-and-h-i).

Comment: Is there any feedback yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending HTTP request data in a legacy encoding like Windows-1252 is not straightforward in node, as there is no native support for these encodings.

Support can be added in the form of an `iconv` library, so it's definitely doable, even if it does not work out of the box.

The following targets [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler), because you are using it, but in principle this applies to any client HTTP library.

Notes:

- Traditional HTTP POSTs are URL-encoded, we will use [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) for this.
- Support for encodings other than UTF-8 will be provided by [qs-iconv](https://github.com/martinheidegger/qs-iconv), as documented in [qs - Dealing with special character sets](https://github.com/ljharb/qs#dealing-with-special-character-sets).
- Restler usually encodes data as UTF-8 if you pass it as a string or plain object, but if you pass a `Buffer`, Restler will send it as it is.
- Setting a proper `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` will ensure the data can be interpreted properly at the receiving end. Since we supply our own data here, we need to set those headers manually.
- Be aware that any character that is not contained in the target charset (Windows-1252 in this case) **will** be encoded as `?` by iconv (`%3F` in URL form) and therefore will be lost.

Code:

```
var rest = require('restler');
var qs = require('qs');
var win1252 = require('qs-iconv/encoder')('win1252');

var requestData = {
  key1: "‘value1‘",
  key2: "‘value2‘"
};

var requestBody = qs.stringify(requestData, { encoder: win1252 });
// => "key1=%91value1%91&key2=%91value2%91"

var requestBuf = new Buffer(requestBody);

rest.post('your/url', {
  data: requestBuf,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1252',
    'Content-Length': requestBuf.length
  }
}).on('complete', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. the qs-iconv thing worked for me. i used your encoding code with my request implementation and the server accepted the urlencoded data as expected.

Comment: any solutions for the same problem, but with a multipart/form-data (contains files) ?

Comment: I don't see how that makes any difference. The request's content type and encoding are not related in any way. That's like asking *"any solution for the same problem, but with text/plain?"*